# Coloring a Ferrers diagram

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, partitions

I've shopped the problem below around a bit and it seems like it might be known, or not that hard to resolve, but so far I've come up empty-handed.

Say that a coloring of the dots of a [Ferrers diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Ferrers_diagram) is *proper* if two dots in the same row or column are never assigned the same color.  Given a proper coloring $c$, let $n_i(c)$ denote the number of dots of color $i$, where we index the colors so that $n_1(c) \ge n_2(c) \ge n_3(c) \ge \cdots.$  In other words, $n_i(c)$ is the number of dots colored with the $i$th most common color.

Say that a proper coloring $c$ of a Ferrers diagram $D$ is *dominant*
if, for *every* proper coloring $c'$ of $D$ and every $i$,
$$n_1(c) + n_2(c) + \cdots + n_i(c) \ge n_1(c') + n_2(c') + \cdots + n_i(c').$$

> Does a Ferrers diagram always have a dominant proper coloring?

If the answer is yes then the proof is probably not going to be easy because it would imply another conjecture that I think is not easy (see [this paper](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/wide.pdf) for more details).  However, perhaps there's an easy counterexample?

**EDIT:**
I should have said that there are easy counterexamples if the condition that the shape be a Ferrers diagram is relaxed.  For example, consider the shape below, where again a proper coloring never assigns the same color to two dots in the same row or column.

```
  * *
  **
***
 *
*
```

By coloring the diagonal all one color, we see that there is a coloring $c$ such that $n_1(c)=5$, $n_2(c)=2$, and $n_3(c)=2$.  On the other hand it is easy to see that there is also a coloring $c'$ with $n_1(c')=n_2(c')=4$ and $n_3(c')=1$.  But it is also easy to see that there is no coloring $c''$ such that $n_1(c'')\ge n_1(c) = 5$ and $n_1(c'')+n_2(c'') \ge n_1(c')+n_2(c') = 8$, so there is no dominant coloring.

**EDIT (18 Nov 2015):** I finally got around to writing a program to check small examples.  Assuming no bug in my code, there is no counterexample among the ${20 \choose 10}-1$ nonempty Ferrers diagrams that fit inside a $10\times 10$ box.  (I could extend this computation a bit further but I'm not sure I see the point.)  Although this obviously doesn't rule out some clever manual construction of a large counterexample, this computation gives me some confidence that the answer to my question is yes.  If the answer is indeed yes, then that makes the question simultaneously more interesting and harder to resolve.

Comment: Do you know the answer if we only require $n_1(c)\ge n_1(c')$ and $n_1(c)+n_2(c)\ge n_1(c')+n_2(c')$?

Comment: I just added the number of partitions arising from such colourings to http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000781.  (be warned that clicking on "Search for values" currently only produces false positives)

Comment: In case you know of a more sensible statistic, please let me know.

Comment: Some data: the second column is the list of (transposed!) partitions
such that a colouring exists.
\begin{align*}
[9]&:[9],\\
[8, 1]&:[8, 1],\\
[7, 2]&:[7, 2],\\
[7, 1, 1]&:[7, 2],\\
[6, 3]&:[6, 3],\\
[6, 2, 1]&:[6, 2, 1], [6, 3],\\
[6, 1, 1, 1]&:[6, 3],\\
[5, 4]&:[5, 4],\\
[5, 3, 1]&:[5, 3, 1], [5, 4],\\
[5, 2, 2]&:[5, 2, 2], [5, 3, 1], [5, 4],\\
[5, 2, 1, 1]&:[5, 3, 1], [5, 4],\\
[5, 1, 1, 1, 1]&:[5, 4],\\
[4, 4, 1]&:[4, 4, 1],\\
[4, 3, 2]&:[4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 1],\\
[4, 3, 1, 1]&:[4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 1],\\
[4, 2, 2, 1]&:[4, 3, 2], [4, 4, 1],\\
[3, 3, 3]&:[3, 3, 3]
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that it is not possible to colour $[3,2,2]$ with multiplicities $[3,2,2]^t$.

Comment: @domotorp : No, I don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: @MartinRubey : It looks to me that you're considering only proper colorings that use the minimum possible number of colors, but your verbal description doesn't say this explicitly.

Comment: That's right.  Isn't that enough?

Comment: @MartinRubey : Say that $\mu$ is a subpartition of $\lambda$ if the multiset of parts of $\mu$ is a submultiset of the multiset of parts of $\lambda$. Then it is not hard to show that $\lambda$ can be colored with multiplicities $\lambda^t$ only if $\mu \ge \mu^t$ for every subpartition $\mu$ of $\lambda$, where $\ge$ denotes dominance order. The "wide partition conjecture" says that this necessary condition is sufficient. This conjecture is still open, and it would follow if every Ferrers diagram has a dominant proper coloring.

Comment: @MartinRubey : "Enough" for what? I was just implicitly suggesting that you clarify your verbal description to eliminate this confusion.

Comment: Do your computations show that each Ferrers diagram gives you a lattice of proper colorings?

Comment: @Tri : I'm not sure if you're addressing your question to me, but the only computations I've done have focused on finding a single dominant proper coloring for each Ferrers diagram. I haven't tried to study the structure of the set of proper colorings for a single Ferrers diagram.

Comment: Yes, I was addressing you.  Seeing if you have a lattice in your examples would give us an idea of how we might prove the property you want---namely, by showing the proper colorings form a lattice in general.  (Seeing if this is true in your examples before embarking on a proof would help convince us that the effort is worthwhile.)

Comment: @Tri: What partial ordering do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: The dominance ordering on the set of proper colorings.

Comment: @Tri, different proper colourings $c$ can have the same sequence of $n_i(c)$. Noting that the sequence $n_i(c)$ is a partition of the size of the Ferrers diagram, we can call it the *colour distribution partition* of $c$; then for each Ferrers diagram of 16 cells or fewer, the distinct colour distribution partitions obtained do form a lattice.